# Prevent user submitting form by hitting enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, preventdefault, enter

How can I prevent the users submitting a contactform by hitting the "Enter" key?
This form is made by using the FormMaster module. The code for the input field is as follows:

```
<div id="dnn_ctr1410_FormMaster_ctl_9d6e1fc4341b453f905425dacbefddf2div">
    <label class="SubHead" id="dnn_ctr1410_FormMaster_lbl_ctl_9d6e1fc4341b453f905425dacbefddf2" for="dnn_ctr1410_FormMaster_ctl_9d6e1fc4341b453f905425dacbefddf2">Message*<br></label>
    <textarea class="wsi_contactform_bottomcell" tabindex="1" id="dnn_ctr1410_FormMaster_ctl_9d6e1fc4341b453f905425dacbefddf2" wrap="off" cols="20" rows="2" name="dnn$ctr1410$FormMaster$ctl_9d6e1fc4341b453f905425dacbefddf2"></textarea>
    <span style="display:none;" class="NormalRed" id="dnn_ctr1410_FormMaster_rfv_313f9f05e5224c4e9bbf2bf6808f43c9"><br>Enter your message.</span>
</div>
```

I used the following script, but without any result:

```
$('.wsi_contactform_bottomcell').on('keypress keydown keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

And by enter I mean the "Enter" key on the keyboard!!

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside the event callback. 
If it is not triggered you are binding the callback to the wrong element. 
If it is triggered look at the "e" variable and see its content.
 Anyway the keyCode should be right.

Answer (score 1):

use e.which

Some browsers use `keyCode` and others use `which`. But with `jQuery` this is normalized so you don't have to think about that. You can just choose the one you prefer.

```
if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

reference [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/LArBW/24/)**

Comment: I just tried this but also without the right result :/

Comment: have you included jquery  and your code document ready

Comment: Thanks for the example. I have included the code + document ready, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you injecting the textarea dynamically in the DOM?

Comment: @marquez How can I find this out? This form comes from a module.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just ignore the keypress and remove a submit button. Instead of that add a this.submit() button. Like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit contactform" onclick="this.submit();">
```

This will remove the "enter key" function from the form.

Comment: this is actually not possible, because this line of code is made dynamicly by the module.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in the past and it worked well for me. This will disable any effect by the Enter key for the entire page:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function disableEnterKey(e)
{
     var key;    
     if(window.event)
          key = window.event.keyCode;
     else
          key = e.which;

     return (key != 13);
}
</script>

<body onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)">
```

If you want to disable form submission for a particular input field, call this from the onKeyPress handler of the input field:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)" >
```

**Edit**

For you specifically:

```
$('.wsi_contactform_bottomcell').on('keypress', disableEnterKey);
```

If the script is never called then you may be trying to bind the handler too early. If the module hasn't added the textarea yet jQuery will fail silently when the selector returns zero results. If this is the case then you will need to come up with a strategy for determining when the module completes its updates to the DOM before trying to bind the event handler.

Comment: There is no "input type" available, see how the module builds up the code

Comment: Sorry, that was just an example. Updated for your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if the element is created dynamically your code will not work because the element doesn't exist.

```
$(document).on("keydown", ".wsi_contactform_bottomcell", function(e) { 
   if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Comment: also this doesn't work, the form ignores the script completely